# how to save an object with 'foreign object' in ormlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm, ormlite

This is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE other (
    id integer primary key autoincrement not null,
    texto text
);

CREATE TABLE tabela (campoid INTEGER primary key autoincrement not null, 
                        camponome text not null, chave int,
                        foreign key (chave) references other(id));
```

and this is my classes:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "tabela")
public class Bean {

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "campoid", generatedId = true)
    private int _id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "camponome")
    private String nome;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = "chave", canBeNull = false)
    private Part chave;
}
```

and other classe mapped

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "other")
public class Part {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "texto")
    private String texto;
}
```

but when i save an Bean object, the Object 'part' does not save too :(

```
        Helper helper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, Helper.class);
        Dao<Bean, Integer> dao = helper.getDao(Bean.class);

        Bean firstBean = new Bean();
        firstBean.setNome("first be persisted");

        Part part = new Part();
        part.setTexto("ANY TEXT");
        firstBean.setChave(part);

        dao.create(firstBean);
```

in my log:

07-13 00:25:26.602: D/BaseMappedStatement(3796): insert data with statement 'INSERT INTO `tabela` (`camponome` ,`chave` ) VALUES (?,?)' and 2 args, changed 1 rows

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when i save an Bean object, the Object 'part' does not save too :(

Right.  [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does not by default persist sub-objects when you create an object.  You can turn on the `foreignAutoCreate = true` flag which will do that for you however.  See the [javadocs for `foreignAutoCreate`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#foreignAutoCreate%28%29).

Your `chave` field should be defined then as:

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = "chave", canBeNull = false,
    foreignAutoCreate = true)
private Part chave;
```

If you want to do it by hand, you should:

```
partDao.create(firstBean.chave);
beanDao.create(firstBean);
```

You create the `Part` in the database *first* because you need the ID from the `Part` which will be saved into your bean.