# How to save object nested inside another object with ormlite?

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, ormlite

I try to save "BestandItem", which is made out of "ScanItem" and a Calendar with Ormlite. After I restart my app (for Android with Android Studio, which I write with Java) the content of ScanItem is gone, but only if it is inside of a Bestanditem.

This is my ScanItem:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "scanItem")
public class ScanItem{
@DatabaseField (generatedId = true)
private int id;
@DatabaseField
private String barcode;
@DatabaseField
private String name;

public ScanItem(String barcode, String name) {
    this.barcode = barcode;
    this.name = name;
}

public ScanItem(){}
```

And this is my BestandItem:

```
@DatabaseTable (tableName = "bestandItem")
public class BestandItem {
@DatabaseField (generatedId = true)
private int id;
@DatabaseField (foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true)
private ScanItem scanItem;
@DatabaseField (dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
private Calendar ablaufDatum;

public BestandItem() {    }

public BestandItem(ScanItem scanItem, Calendar ablaufDatum) {
    this.scanItem = scanItem;
    this.ablaufDatum = ablaufDatum;
}
```

Some of the things I have tried: 
- [Ormlite Documentation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Persisted-Types) 
- [First Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745652/saving-nested-foreign-objects-with-ormlite-on-android) 
- [Second Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626685/how-to-save-an-object-with-foreign-object-in-ormlite)

For more code see my github project: 
 [Github SmartFridge](https://github.com/ChristopherPS96/SmartFridge?files=1)

My Ormlite Database has a UtilConfigClass and a always updated config.txt. 
What did I do wrong here? Why dosn't save the ScanItem right?

After some checks, I can say that the other methods work just fine. (only after the lost of the ScanItem, I get NullPointerException). My conclusion is, that the problem is the constructor of the BestandItem.

I think I did something wrong with generatedID and/or foreignAutoCreate, but I dont really understand how do use it properly.
Also what exactly foreignAutoRefresh does.

I have tried to change the ID and generatedId around, because I think there lies the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests and countless trys, I now have a solution.
Because the barcode inside of ScanItem is unique, I could use it for a ID, instead of a generated id.
And with an existing ID, the programm now works.